# How do I cite a product that cannot be sourced commercially

Tags: phd

I used a product in my PhD that is not available to buy. Our lab was given it as a free sample from a company that was considering developing this product. How do I cite it? Thank you

Comment: Check with your PI about whether there are restrictions that were put in place with the donation. There may have been a contract limiting disclosure. Some companies might treat this as _trade secret_ information.

Comment: Ask that company

Answer (score 1):

In your list of materials, you can just add a parenthetical after identifying the product and the manufacturer.  Something like "(not yet commercially available, but obtained by special arrangement)" should be fine.